# How to convert this type of XML into CSV

Tags: php, xml, csv, xml-parsing

I have this type of XML file

Example of file part:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<ponudba podjetje="SO d.o.o." velja_od="23.09.2012 @ 12:30:48">
    <artikel koda="LS593EAR" naziv="HP ENVY 17-2199e" kategorija="Prenosniki" podkategorija="Hewlett Packard (HP)" v_akciji="ne" kosovnost="več">
    <opis>
    HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)
    </opis>
    <opis_detail>
    HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)<br/><table> <col width="25%" /> <col /> <tbody> <tr> <th>Procesor</th> <td>Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM / 2.00 GHz / Quad-Core</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Delovni pomnilnik</th> <td>8 GB DDR3</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Trdi disk</th> <td>1 TB (1000 GB) / 5400 / SATA</td> </tr> <tr> <th>LCD zaslon</th> <td>43,9 cm (17,3'') Full HD HP Ultra BrightView Infinity Display (1920x1080)</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Grafična kartica</th> <td>AMD Radeon™ HD 6850 Graphics</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Optična enota</th> <td>SuperMulti DVD-RW Double Layer</td> </tr> <tr> <th>USB 2.0</th> <td>2x</td> </tr> <tr> <th>USB 3.0</th> <td>1x</td> </tr>    <tr> <th>eSATA</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>HDMI</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>WiFi</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Bluetooth</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>WWAN</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Spletna kamera</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Card Reader</th> <td>da</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Express Card</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>TV kartica</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Finger Print</th> <td>ne</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Vhodne naprave</th> <td>brez</td> </tr>     <tr> <th>Operacijski sistem</th> <td>Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)</td> </tr> <tr> <th>Država uvoza</th> <td>Italijanska tipkovnica (priložene SLO nalepke)</td> </tr>  <tr> <th>Stanje modela</th> <td>HP Renew</td> </tr>     </tbody> </table>
    </opis_detail>
    <garancija_v_mesecih>12</garancija_v_mesecih>
    <cena_v_EUR>1.049,00</cena_v_EUR>
    <proizvajalec>HP</proizvajalec>
    <stanje>na zalogi</stanje>
    <url_foto_artikla>
    http://www.so-doo.si/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/0/c02034964.jpg.hri_4.jpg
    </url_foto_artikla>
    <vec_fotk_artikla>
    <slika href="http://www.so-doo.si/media/catalog/product/c/0/c02034982.jpg.hri_4.jpg"/>
    <slika href="http://www.so-doo.si/media/catalog/product/c/0/c02034991.jpg.hri_4.jpg"/>
    </vec_fotk_artikla>
    <teza_artikla_v_kg>2.9000</teza_artikla_v_kg>
    </artikel>
```

Now I try to convert this XML file into CSV using this type of code:

```php
<?php

$filexml='so_feed.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('sofeed.csv', 'w');
foreach ($xml->naziv as $naziv) {
    fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($naziv),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
?>`
```

where so_feed.xml is input XML file and sofeed.csv is output CSV file, and field "naziv" is node for which I need data.

But I get only empty csv file. Some help, pls? :) Also when I use "artikel" node, i dont get whole info, just a part:(

When using "artikel" array I get all info, except "kode" and "naziv", on english, that is "SKU" and "Product name" so you know that this is most important part and i can not get it, I only get word "Array" instead those data

This is what my  output CSV looks like :

```
<!-- language: lang-csv -->

Array,"HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)","HP ENVY 17-2199el, Intel Core i7-2630QM (2.0 GHz), 17.3'' FHD AG LED 3D, 8 GB DDR3 (2x 4 GB), 1 TB, BluRay, ATI Radeon HD6850 1024 MB, WiFi, Bluetooth, Webcam, 3D glasses, Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)<br/><table>
        <col width=""25%"" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Procesor</th>
                <td>Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM / 2.00 GHz / Quad-Core</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Delovni pomnilnik</th>
                <td>8 GB DDR3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Trdi disk</th>
                <td>1 TB (1000 GB) / 5400 / SATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>LCD zaslon</th>
                <td>43,9 cm (17,3'') Full HD HP Ultra BrightView Infinity Display (1920x1080)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Grafična kartica</th>
                <td>AMD Radeon™ HD 6850 Graphics</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Optična enota</th>
                <td>SuperMulti DVD-RW Double Layer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>USB 2.0</th>
                <td>2x</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>USB 3.0</th>
                <td>1x</td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <th>eSATA</th>
                <td>da</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>HDMI</th>
                <td>da</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>WiFi</th>
                <td>da</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Bluetooth</th>
                <td>da</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>WWAN</th>
                <td>ne</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Spletna kamera</th>
                <td>da</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Card Reader</th>
                <td>da</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Express Card</th>
                <td>ne</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>TV kartica</th>
                <td>ne</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Finger Print</th>
                <td>ne</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Vhodne naprave</th>
                <td>brez</td>
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                <th>Operacijski sistem</th>
                <td>Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Država uvoza</th>
                <td>Italijanska tipkovnica (priložene SLO nalepke)</td>
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                <th>Stanje modela</th>
                <td>HP Renew</td>
            </tr>       
    </tbody>
    </table>",12,"1.049,00",HP,"na zalogi",http://www.so-doo.si/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/0/c02034964.jpg.hri_4.jpg,,2.9000
```

After applying code:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

<?php
// The order here determines the order in the output CSV file
$columns = array(
    'koda',
    'naziv',
    'kategorija',
    'podkategorija',
    'v_akciji',
    'kosovnost'

);

// This will be used later on to correctly sort in the attribute values
// Note: the third paramter of "array_fill" determines what value to use
// in case a node lacks an attribute
$csv_blueprint = array_combine(
    $columns,
    array_fill(0, count($columns), '')
);

$data = array($columns);
$filexml = 'so_feed.xml';

if ( !file_exists($filexml) ) {
    // Do some error routine
} else {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
    $artikel = $xml->artikel;

    if ( !count($artikel) ) {
        // Stop processing 'cause there's nothing to do
    } else {
        foreach ( $artikel as $item )
        {
            // Clone the row blueprint to leave the original unspoiled
            $row = $csv_blueprint;

            $attr = $item->attributes();
            foreach ( $attr as $key => $value ) {
                $row[$key] = (string) $value;
            }
            // Append the current row to the overall output data but
            // be sure to strip off the indexes and pass a numerical array
            $data[] = array_values($row);
        }

        // The rest is up to you ... do whatever you need to :D
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
?>
```

I got only few fields output, defined in code:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

$columns = array(
    'koda',
    'naziv',
    'kategorija',
    'podkategorija',
    'v_akciji',
    'kosovnost'
```

How to get all other attributes output in csv?

Comment: Did you check that `get_object_vars($naziv)` returns a proper array?

Comment: Hello. I am sorry, how to do this? I am new in all of this, so please understand me. But I am learning

Comment: Replace the `fputcs..` line with `var_dump(get_object_vars($naziv));` and have a look at the output in your browser.

Comment: I gaet everything when i use "artikel" instead "naziv" except "koda" and "naziv" field, just "@" sign ?! In csv instead those fields is written "Array"

Comment: You do know the difference between a node and its attributes? `naziv` is an attribute which cannot be accessed with the `->` operator. I think you should give an example of the desired CSV's structure.

Comment: If you mean which content csv filee need to have, then this is example CSV file in question, but only need to have fields and values KODA, NAZIV, KATEGORIJA, PODKATEGORIJA, V_AKCIJI and KOSOVNOST also included. Is this info you ask about?

Comment: Yep, that's what I was asking for. I'll put together an example for you but it'll take some time (check back in around an hour).

Comment: Well, what to tell then thank you, thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, this is what I came up with. I've tried to be very verbose to help you understand what's going on.

```
// The order here determines the order in the output CSV file
$columns = array(
    'koda',
    'naziv',
    'kategorija',
    'podkategorija',
    'v_akciji',
    'kosovnost'
);

// This will be used later on to correctly sort in the attribute values
// Note: the third paramter of "array_fill" determines what value to use
// in case a node lacks an attribute
$csv_blueprint = array_combine(
    $columns,
    array_fill(0, count($columns), '')
);

$data = array($columns);
$filexml = 'so_feed.xml';

if ( !file_exists($filexml) ) {
    // Do some error routine
} else {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
    $artikel = $xml->artikel;

    if ( !count($artikel) ) {
        // Stop processing 'cause there's nothing to do
    } else {
        foreach ( $artikel as $item ) {
            // Clone the row blueprint to leave the original unspoiled
            $row = $csv_blueprint;

            $attr = $item->attributes();
            foreach ( $attr as $key => $value ) {
                $row[$key] = (string) $value;
            }
            // Append the current row to the overall output data but
            // be sure to strip off the indexes and pass a numerical array
            $data[] = array_values($row);
        }

        // The rest is up to you ... do whatever you need to :D
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Extending the former code to reflect the need for additional columns.

- Extend the `$columns` array the way you want to incorporate the
  necessary data (e.g. opis)

  ```
  $columns = array(
      'koda',
      'naziv',
      'kategorija',
      'opis',  // Arbitrarily added an extra column here
      'podkategorija',
      'v_akciji',
      'kosovnost'
  );
  ```
- Iterate over `<ponudba/>` instead of `artikel`

  ```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
  //$artikel = $xml->artikel;
  $ponudbas = $xml->ponudba;
  ...
      foreach ( $ponudbas as $ponudba ) {
          // Clone the row blueprint to leave the original unspoiled
          $row = $csv_blueprint;
  ```
- Add the attributes of any `artikel` node just like before
- Additionally iterate over the added columns (those that correspond to nodes) and save their
  value within the `$row[NODE_NAME / COLUMN NAME]` bucket

Comment: Thank you, just quick question, how to have all results from XML file in my CSV? Just to expand columns? Becouse in same file I need cena, opis, etc...Also, how to save this output in "nsome_name.csv" form on my computer? Like in my simple code example in start? I am really sorry for inconvenience, but i see you know what you are doing and I just want to learn.

Comment: Hmm, when I iterate over ponudba, result is blank page, so I supose that is no result?